# how to give css for arranging label, textbox and text area side by side in the same line

Tags: html, css

i have given code as below. if am removing that breaks when clicking on more the data and the next line containing the above are colliding and there place has been changing can anyone help me by saying what was wrong and how to overcome it thanks.

css

```
      .label_left {
width: 35%;
float: left;
text-align: right;
line-height: 30px;
   }
.text_right1 {
width: 27%;
float:left;
}
.text_right2 {
width: 27%;
float:left;
}
```

and html is as follows

```
       <div class="label_left"><label>
        What was your ACTUAL state tourism budget for the following categories for FY 2011-2012? :<br>
        <span class="comment more">(*Personnel Services;*Other Administrative Costs;*Advertising;Sales Promotion;*Printing and Promotion;*Inquiry Fulfillment;*Press and Public Relations;*Research;*Industry Relations;*Grant Programs;*Website Development/Maintainance;*Cooperative Marketing Dollars - state/territory contribution only,and *Other) (SEE THE "CATEGORIES" TAB FOR A DEFINITON OF EACH CATEGORY)<br>
        NOTE: Recognizing that not all states have welcome centers and film divisions, please omit from your state's FY 2010-2011 tourism budget.</span></label></div>

    <div class="text_right1" ><br><br><input type="text" name="state" id="state"  value="" size="30" style="height:20px;" /></div>
    <div class="text_right2"><br><br><textarea name="state_note" id="state_note" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
    <br  /><br  /><br  /><br><br><br><br  /><br  /><br  /><br  /><br  /><br  /><br><br  /><br  /><br  /><br><br  /><br  /><br  /><br>
    </div>

    <div class="label_left"><label>
        Total amount of public sector funds for ACTUAL FY 2011-2012 budget  :<br>
        <span class="comment more">(e.g., state general revenue fund appropriation, receipts from a dedicated or earmarked tax such as lodging/tourism/rental car and/or sales tax, lottery receipts, federal funds such as Transportation Enhancement monies, etc. DO NOT INCLUDE SPECIAL LEGISLATIVE APPROPRIATIONS IN WHICH THE TOURISM OFFICE IS SIMPLY THE ADMINISTRATOR OF THIS "PASS THROUGH" APPROPRIATION.)</span> </label></div>
    <div class="text_right1"><br><br><input type="text" name="public_amt" id="public_amt"  value=""  size="30" style="height:20px;" /></div>
    <div class="text_right2"><br><br><textarea name="state_note" id="state_note" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
    <br  /><br  /><br  /><br><br><br><br  /><br  /><br  /><br><br><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use style="display:inline" on div or other way use flot:left to all div

Comment: It's a `br` jungle there

Comment: can you give code for above in your pattern please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/HVgF6/

CSS

```
.label_left {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.text_right1 {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.text_right2 {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.clr {
    clear: both;
}
input, texarea {
    width: 154px;
    float: left;
    verticle-align: top;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. how to use tooltipsy instaed of more and less for the above code